# Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIScreen'

Tags: ios, swift

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

On this line I get the above error. Based on previous posts, I see that it got changed in Swift 3.0, but I can't figure out how to fix it. How do I change this?

Comment: its `UIScreen.main.bounds`

Comment: FYI - that's Swift 2 code.

Comment: Others have given you the answer, but not how to get it. What you should do is go to Xcode, select "Documentation and API Reference" from the help menu, search on `UIScreen`, and then scan through the sections of the documentation. You'll quickly find "Getting the Available Screens", and in that section, you'll see a class variable `main`. Alternatively, you could try searching for the string "main" in that document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change to `window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`

Main change is from `.mainScreen()` to `.main`

Mainly Swift 3 changes a lot of their function calls to be property-type